# Filtering out employees that do not meet some criteria, using list comprehensions

Tags: python

Right now I have a list of dictionaries. In order to filter out all the entries I do not want included in the list, I am running it through multiple list comprehensions.

Is there a more Pythonic or better way to write these comprehensions that seem repetitive?

```
#FILTER OUT ALL EMPLOYEES WHO WILL NOT BE FACTORED INTO METRICS
inScope = [s for s in set2 if s['LEAD_TIME'] >= 0]#lead times 0 or more
set2 = inScope

inScope = [s for s in set2 if s['WRK_RLTN_DSC'] != "INDEPENDENT CONTRACTOR"]#not independent contractor
set2 = inScope

inScope = [s for s in set2 if s['WRK_RLTN_DSC'] != "OUTSIDE CONSULTANT"]#not outside consultant
set2 = inScope

inScope = [s for s in set2 if s['WRK_RLTN_DSC'] != "OUTSIDE CONTRACTOR"]#not outside contractor
set2 = inScope

inScope = [s for s in set2 if s['WRK_RLTN_DSC'] != "EMP OF STRATEGIC INVESTMENT CO"]#not emp of strategic investment co
set2 = inScope

inScope = [s for s in set2 if s['BUS_GRP_CD'] != "FIL"]#In scope after removal of FIL Int'l Associates
set2 = inScope
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest refactoring is as follows:

```
CONDITIONS = [
    ('WRK_RLTN_DSC', 'INDEPENDENT CONTRACTOR'), 
    ...
]
set2 = [s for s in set2 if s['LEAD_TIME'] >= 0]
for key, excl in CONDITIONS:
    set2 = [s for s in set2 if s[key] != excl]
```

Note:

1. You can assign straight back to `set2`, getting rid of the temporary `inScope` variable;
2. I have factored out the multiple checks into a simple loop over a list of keys and values; and
3. I have consistently used single quotes for string literals, rather than a mix of single and double.

However, although neater than your current code, this is still relatively inefficient, as it builds multiple lists; you could instead try something like:

```
set2 = [s for s in set2 if s['LEAD_TIME'] >= 0 and 
        all(s[key] != excl for key, excl in conditions)]
```

which reduces it to a single list comprehension. An alternative would be to incorporate e.g.:

```
INVALID_WRK = {
    'INDEPENDENT CONTRACTOR',
    ...
}

... s['WRK_RLTN_DSC'] not in INVALID_WRK ...
```

as you check that key multiple times.

Comment: I keep get the following error  File "test.py", line 15
    'INDEPENDENT CONTRACTOR',
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It is telling me there is a syntax error with the comma

Comment: Which version of Python? If prior to 2.7 you can't have set literals.

Answer (score 1):

There are 6 conditions (maybe more) and right now you're doing 6 loops to filter them out. This is very inefficient.

I understand that list comprehension is a great tool but you shouldn't use it at such an expense of performance. Imagine if this was the code :

```
inScope = []
for s in set2:
    if s['LEAD_TIME'] >= 0:
        inScope.append(s)

set2 = inScope
for s in set2:
    if  s['WRK_RLTN_DSC'] != "INDEPENDENT CONTRACTOR":
        inScope.append(s)

set2 = inScope
#...
```

Surely you would notice something is wrong? This is basically what your code is doing.

I believe the most readable way (although not "pythonic") would be to use to good ol' `for` and `if` operators.

```
inScope = []
for s in set2:
    if  s['LEAD_TIME'] >= 0 and s['WRK_RLTN_DSC'] != "INDEPENDENT CONTRACTOR": #...
        inScope.append(s)
```

If you *absolutely* want to use list comprehension, what I would suggest is to define a lambda and use it then.

```
var conditions = lambda s : s['LEAD_TIME'] >= 0 and s['WRK_RLTN_DSC'] != "INDEPENDENT CONTRACTOR" #...

inScope = [s for s in set2 if conditions(s)]
```

or even better (which is also "pythonic"):

```
inScope = filter(conditions, set2)
```

(I just realized this is an old question, this code assumes a python 3.* version)